# Counting cells in Excel with with same interior color using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to count cells that are duplicate.  In a column, I first find the duplicates using Conditional Formatting.  I highlight my cells yellow (RGB(255,255,255)).  However, when I try to count the highlighted cells, for some reason my vba does not detect them.

If I highlight the cells over the Conditional Formatting my function detects the color and counts correctly.  Any ideas on why I can't detect the conditional formatting?

```
Function colorCount(arr As Variant, r As Integer, G As Integer, B As Integer) As Integer
Dim x As Variant
Dim xRow As Integer
Dim xCol As Integer

colorCount = 0
For Each x In arr.Cells

xRow = x.Row
xCol = x.Column

If Cells(xRow, xCol).Interior.Color = RGB(r, G, B) Then
colorCount = colorCount + 1
End If
Next

End Function
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you use the logic that you apply to the CF for the count? CF does not set the Interior.Color, so that approach will never fly.

Comment: FYI `Cells(xRow, xCol).Interior.Color` is the same here as `x.Interior.Color` so your code can be much shorter (even though it will not work for the reason outlined by @teylyn)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not using any logic to my duplicates. I'm using the excel built in Conditional Formatting. However, the link @pnuts sent may be useful.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that conditional formatting doesn't actually color the cell in the same way that a 'traditional' format does.

There are two ways to tackle this:

1. Use VBA to detect your duplicates:

   ```
   ' dupe check requires cells to be highighted
   YourWB.Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select

   ' now check that row for dupes, and flag each dupe with some formatting
   Dim d As Object, e
   Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
   For Each e In Intersect(Columns(ActiveCell.Column), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
       If e.Value <> vbNullString Then
           If Not d.exists(e.Value) Then d(e.Value) = 1 Else _
               e.Font.ColorIndex = 4
       End If
   Next
   ```
2. Detect the applied conditional color.

This is a little more complex, I used the code [on this page](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=190)